# Chromium keeps crashing

Tags: 10.04, chromium

I was clearing the cache/temp internet files from chromium, and did a silly thing, while it was still clearing, I close chromium too quickly...

Now when I try to clear the cache/temp internet files, chromium just disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromium settings are stored in ~/.config/chromium. it could be that some of these files are corrupted. Deleting the chromium-folder will reset the settings/state of chromium to that of a fresh install. You will lose all your bookmarks and settings so make a backup of that folder first.

Answer (score 0):

As an ademdun to Kenneth Venken's answer, there is a way to preserve a large quantity of your browser data, including bookmarks and settings. Open up the Chromium preferences menu and click on the 'Personal' tab. The first option there will allow you to sync all the information listed there to your Google account, meaning all you ahve to do to access it if you delete your configuration folder is log back into your Google account and it'll all come right back in.